# Find the number of pair (A,B)

Tags: combinatorics

For a pair (A,B) of subsets of the set X ={1,2,3,..,100} let A∆B denote
the set of all elements of X which belong to exactly one of A or B. The
number of pairs (A,B) of subsets of X such that A∆B = {2,4,6,8,...,100}
is

(A) 2^151 (B) 2^102 (C) 2^101 (D) 2^100.

**My approach**- all even nummber should be taken by both A and B. No even number is common between them. Odd number taken by A should taken by B also. But I can't count how much pair should be there.

Please help me to find out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Every odd number is either in both of $A$ and $B$, or neither of $A$ and $B$.

Every even number is either in $A$ and not in $B$, or not in $A$ and in $B$.

Therefore, for each number (even or odd), you have two choices to make, so there are $2^{100}$ such pairs.

Answer (score 0):

For any $A,$ does there exist a $B$ such that $A\Delta B$

Is this $B$ unique?

If the answer to both is yes, then $A$ can be any subsets of $X.$

How many subsets of $X$ are there?

Maybe you could enumerate all of the A,B pairs in a simper example of a the same problem.

i.e. $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$

Find all of the $A,B$ pairs such that $A\Delta B = \{2,4\}$

What do you think might be the relevance of the numbers chosen in the multiple choice answers?